# Classifcation/Decision Trees and Choosing Splits

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, classification, decision-tree

This is a very basic example.  But I am doing some data analysis and am continually finding myself writing very similar SQL count queries like so to generate probability tables.

My tables are defined such that a value of 0 implies that an event did not take place while a value of 1 implies that the event did take place.

```
  > sqldf("select count(distinct Date) from joinedData where C_O_Above_prevHigh = 0 and  C_O_Below_prevLow = 0")
  count(distinct Date)
1                 1081

> sqldf("select count(distinct Date) from joinedData where C_O_Above_prevHigh = 0 and C_O_Below_prevLow = 0 and E_halfGap = 1")
  count(distinct Date)
1                  956

> sqldf("select count(distinct Date) from joinedData where C_O_Above_prevHigh = 1 OR C_O_Below_prevLow = 1 and E_halfGap = 1")
  count(distinct Date)
1                  504
```

In the above example, my predictor variables are `C_O_Above_prevHigh` and `C_O_Below_prevLow` my outcome variable is `E_halfGap`. There are several cases where there might be more predictor variables e.g. `Time`

Rather than doing the above and manually entering all my queries with different permuations, is there anything available in R or some other application that will:

1) output the potential probability paths based on my predictors?
2) allow me to choose how to split the paths

I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all totals and subtotals, 
you can use `CUBE BY` in SQL (but it is not in SQLite)
or `addmargins` in R.

```
addmargins( Titanic )
# More readable:
ftable( addmargins( Titanic ) )
```

If you want to build a decision tree,
you can use the `rpart` package
or check the 
[machine learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html)
or 
[graphical models](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html) 
task views

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to cubes.